# Java failed manageServlet

Tags: java

So i was trying to make my manageServlet but when i start my application an press on a bottun i get the error :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet. , here is a link to the whole project if needed : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LJ3SIo8uHMV3M4VWxwT2ZvNzQ/view?usp=sharing

I think this is the faulty code :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;
    if (request.getParameter("skigebiedZoek") != null) {
        String skigebiedZoek = request.getParameter("skigebiedZoek");
        Skigebied skigebied = daskigebied.getSkigebied(skigebiedZoek);
        if (skigebied != null) {
            request.setAttribute("skigebied", skigebied);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("skigebied.jsp");
        } else {
            String foutboodschap = "Geen skigebied gevonden";
            request.setAttribute("foutboodschap", foutboodschap);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("fout.jsp");
        }
    } else if (request.getParameter("hotelKnop") != null) {
        Hotel hotel = dahotel.getHotel();
        request.setAttribute("hotel", hotel);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("hotel.jsp");
    }
    else if (request.getParameter("overzichtHotelsKnop") != null) {
        ArrayList<Hotel> overzichtHotels = dahotel.getOverzichtHotels();
        request.setAttribute("overzichtHotels", overzichtHotels);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("overzichtHotels.jsp");
    }
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

And this is my index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>PROJECT SNOWMORE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="headercontainer">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Ga op reis naar de sneeuw</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <form action="ManageServlet" >
      <p>Waarvan wil je de details bekijken?</p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Toon specifiek skigebied" name="skigebiedKnop" /> <input type="text" name="skigebiedZoek" size="5" /></p>          
      <p><input type="submit" value="Toon specifiek hotel" name="hotelKnop"/></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Toon hotels" name="overzichtHotelsKnop"/></p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I fixed it but now there is this an error that says :
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym 
    type: fact.it.www.dataaccess.DASkigebied.getSkigebied

and the line that gives the error :     Skigebied skigebied = daskigebied.getSkigebied(skigebiedZoek);

And this is DASkigebied :

```
package fact.it.www.dataaccess;

import fact.it.www.beans.Skigebied;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DASkigebied {

private Connection connection = null;

// Constructor met 4 parameters
public DASkigebied(String url, String login, String password, String driver) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(driver);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
}

public void close() throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}

public Skigebied getSkigebied() {
    Skigebied skigebied = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM skigebied");

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            skigebied = new Skigebied();
            skigebied.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            skigebied.setSkigebied(resultSet.getString("skigebied"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
    return skigebied;
}
```

}

Comment: search your whole source code for a line like this `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.")`

Comment: that worked thanks but now it gives another error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: fact.it.www.dataaccess.DASkigebied.getSkigebied

Comment: That is a compilation error, you need to show your code so we can get what is the error with it?

Comment: i edited my question so that you can see were the error is :) (+ thanks for the help on the first part of my question)

Comment: Do you need more info ?